# Conda run -n env_name ignores the environments R_HOME variable

Tags: r, conda

I have created a conda env for a certain tool, which depends on R.
I’m trying to run the tool without activating the conda env, as follows:

```
conda run env_name tool_name
```

However, I get the warning: “ignoring environment value of R_HOME”.
Needless to say that my tool does not run, because it does not have access to R version in its own environment.

Any ideas as of why this happens and how to fix it?

thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to give the details - this is not an abstract problem.